# What happens to the Park family after the final "episode"?

Tags: parasite

What could have possibly happened to the Park Family in *Parasite* after Mr. Park gets stabbed, Mrs. Park faints, the son gets seizures?
No one seems to be discussing about it and I took the courage to ask it.

Answer (score 4):

The scenes of the movie after the party seemed fairly definitive, so I'm not sure if you missed it, or are asking about what happens after *that*.  After the party, we follow up with the Kim family. We see that the daughter died from her stab wound, while the son and mother are on probation for fraud, and nobody can find Mr. Kim.  The son discovers that his father is living in the bunker in the mansion, and promises to himself (or the audience) that he will try to earn enough money to buy the mansion so that his father isn't trapped.

That is all we can say for certain.  What happens to either the Kim family or Park family in the future is unknown.  As such, any further discussion would be conjecture.

Comment: I am just asking of the possible situations that could've happened to the Park Family since the movie doesn't show what happens to the son, if the the son does due to seizures or if the husband survived the stab from Mr. Kim and what happened to the Mrs Park and her daughter!! That's all. Just your imagination. Nothing else!!